# mysql select with left join query

Tags: mysql

my code is

```
select class.name as classname,
       class.hours as hours, 
       teachers.first_name as teacherFirstName, 
       teachers.last_name as teacherLastName 
from teachers,class 
left join class_teachers cl on class.id = cl.class_ref  
left join class_teachers cl1 on teachers.id = cl1.teachers_ref
```

there is an error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'teachers.id' in 'on clause
```

when I interchange class and teachers the error is

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'class.id' in 'on clause
```

do you guys have an idea whats the problem?

edit

```
CREATE TABLE `class` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hours` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `class_teachers` (
  `class_ref` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `teachers_ref` int(11) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE `teachers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

class_teachers is an intermediary table. this database should make possible that a class should have multiple teacher. for example PE class can have separate teachers for boys and girls. the query should show list of class with teachers names, class name and number of class hours

class table

```
id  name     hours
1   science     3
2   math        5
```

teachers table

```
id  first_name  last_name
1   Ronald      Manlapao
2   hello       goodbye
3   elise       elise
4   me          me
```

class_teachers table

```
class_ref   teachers_ref
2                   2
1                   1

1                   2
```

tried

```
select c.name as classname, c.hours as hours, t.first_name as teacherFirstName, t.last_name as teacherLastName 
from teachers t, class c
left join class_teachers cl on (c.id = cl.class_ref and t.id = cl.teachers_ref)
```

but still the same error

updated class_teachers table to class_teachers_section to include section. the idea is a class can include different sections with different teachers. for example a grade 1 PE class can include all sections (lets pretend 3 sections)  ...  teacher for boys will be different for girls

```
select class.name as classname, 
   class.hours as hours, 
   teachers.first_name as teacherFirstName, 
   teachers.last_name as teacherLastName,
   section.name as sectionName
 from class_teachers_section cls 
 left join class on class.id = cls.class_ref  
 left join teachers on teachers.id = cls.teachers_ref
 left join section on section.id = cls.section_ref
 where section.name = 'grade 1'
```

Comment: You have a confusing mix of an incomplete implicit join and two explicit left joins here. Can you post the structure of these 3 tables, via `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` along with a sample of what output you expect from a small sample rowset of each

Comment: Please edit your question above to include this information - don't post it in comments.

Comment: i already edited it  ...   im sorry im new here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you change the primary table to class_teachers, and the teachers and class table should be referenced.

```
select class.name as classname, 
       class.hours as hours, 
       teachers.first_name as teacherFirstName, 
       teachers.last_name as teacherLastName 
from class_teachers cl 
left join class on class.id = cl.class_ref  
left join teachers on teachers.id = cl.teachers_ref
```

Your porblem is you use `from a,b` before `left join`, then the `left join` on clause can only find `b.id`, so when you interchange class and teachers, you get differnt error.

If you realy want to crossjoin teachers and class first, use `join` insead of `,`.
Use `left join` or `full outer join` will be the same, because you done have any join conditions.

```
select class.name as classname,
       class.hours as hours, 
       teachers.first_name as teacherFirstName, 
       teachers.last_name as teacherLastName 
from teachers
join class 
left join class_teachers cl 
     on  class.id = cl.class_ref  
     and teachers.id = cl.teachers_ref
```

Comment: the first statement worked ...   what if I will add another intermediary table (class_section), will the select statement work?

Comment: It depends on what you need, the first statement return all the relations of  classes and teachers. If you add class_section, what kind of result you want? I suggest you should make the result data before you write the statement.

Comment: same as above plus name of section...table class_section contains class_ref and section_ref (id from section)  ..  im afraid I have to use from a,b if I add an intermediary table (class_section)

Comment: `from a,b` we only use as inner join, and use where clause include the join condition. So if you add class_section, append `left join class_ref on class_ref.class_ref = class_id ` , that's ok. Use join for complex join is recommended.

Comment: updated class_teachers to class_teachers_sections  ...   edited my question  ...  thanks for your help :-)